# Android, логгирование во время REST запроса

Tags: android, rest, retrofit

Совершаю простой rest запрос посредством Retrofit 2:

```
 @POST("users/put")
 Call<DefaultResponse<User>> postUserId(@Query("UserID") String userId,
                                        @Query("Name") String Name);
```

Всё успешно отправляется и логгируется благодаря

```
'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1
```

И далее

```
 private static HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger() {
        @Override
        public void log(String message) {
            Log.d("RESTLog", message);
        }
    }).setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

private OkHttpClient logger = new 
OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).client(logger).build();
```

Недавно встала задача: подписывать запросы. Для этого я использую другой interceptor:

```
private static OkHttpClient signClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new SigningInterceptor()).build();
```

Причём
`new SigningInterceptor()` сделан не мною, он лютый и модифицировать его не выходит. Логгер теперь использовать не получается, т.к его место занял подписчик, так же не выйдет использовать stetho, потому что их логгирование по тому же принципу работает - нужно вставить их interceptor.

Вопрос: как мне логгировать REST запрос, не утратив возможности его подписывать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот как выглядит метод билдера `OkHttp`

```
public Builder addInterceptor(Interceptor interceptor) {
  if (interceptor == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("interceptor == null");
  interceptors.add(interceptor);
  return this;
}
```

https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.java

Добавляйте интерцепторов сколько надо.